# remove commented characters from line

Tags: notepad++

Can I  remove everything in comments and the single quotes between procedure name and get it back to one line?

below example

```
Create procedure --v2.1 bla lba
"P_FLY_ME"
```

output desired

```
Create procedure P_FLY_ME
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In notepad++

- open find and replace dialog (CTRL+H)
- check "regular expression"
- find what:
  `(Create procedure )--.*\r?\n"([^"]*)"`

  - `(Create procedure )` - matches "create procedure" and stores it in capture group 1 (first set of brackets)
  - `--.*\r?\n` - matches comment and linebreak
  - `"([^"]*)"` - matches name and stores it in capture group 2 (without quotes)
- replace to:
  `\1\2` - replace found string to capture groups 1 and 2
- press "replace all"

Comment: This worked but could you please explain what happened exactly?

Comment: I've updated my answer, I hope it's more clear now.

Comment: I had output ilke this `Create procedureP_FLY_ME` how to add space between them

Comment: add a space between \1 and \2, or use `(Create procedure )` exactly as in my answer: with a space before the closing bracket.